# How to custom the sorting of values of a Pandas dataframe by several columns?

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting, lambda

I have a pandas dataframe `df_tgt_viz` and I am trying to sort it by the first *2 cols.* - *(pandas = 1.1.5)*

```
   value_lvl_1         value_lvl_2  metrics/pageviews   
    Country 1       1 to 5 minutes             1523.0 
    Country 2     10 to 30 minutes           140602.0  
    Country 1     10 to 30 minutes             4463.0
    Country 1     30 to 60 minutes            84882.0  
    Country 1     30 to 60 minutes              403.0 
    Country 2      5 to 10 minutes              922.0 
    Country 2      5 to 10 minutes            67802.0    
    Country 1     30 to 60 minutes            84882.0 
    Country 1   less than 1 minute            14212.0
```

I intend to use the `sort_values` method with the argument `key=lambda x: x.map(custom_dict)` to give the sorting order of the *2nd col.*

```
custom_dict = \
    {
        'less than 1 minute': 0,
        '1 to 5 minutes': 1,
        '5 to 10 minutes': 2,
        '10 to 30 minutes': 3,
        '30 to 60 minutes': 4
    }
```

**Question 1**

How can I instruct the double sorting of values that I need? My attempt was to pass a list to the `key` argument, but this throws an error:

```
df_tgt_viz.sort_values(by=['value_lvl_1', 'value_lvl_2', 'metrics/orders'],
                       ascending=[True, True, False],
                       key=[lambda x: x.map(x), lambda x: x.map(custom_dict)],
                       inplace=False)
```

**Question 2**

How to additionally sort the values of the *1st col.* by grouping `value_lvl_1` and descending the `metrics/pageviews` per each group? Such that the country with total `metrics/pageviews` is on top.

Comment: If you use key, the *callable* will be called for each column in `by` independently per [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas-dataframe-sort-values).  Therefore, you can't sort value_lvl_1 differently from value_lvl_2 when using the key parameter.   I would suggest you create help columns to sort on.

Comment: Thank you - If no distinct & double sorting can’t be done, a helper column is a good suggestion in this case.